# If statement true regardless of input

Tags: vb.net

Recently I have been tasked with making a calculator in VB. It must include stuff like logic or denary/binary/hex conversions. When I was making the binary->denary conversion I encountered a thing where an if statement checking if the inputted number is binary always returned true and activated. Here is the code for the binary conversion system: **(please forgive me for the goto's)**

```
        Private Sub bbin_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles bbin.Click
        If temp = IsNumeric(inputbox.Text) Then
            MessageBox.Show("Value Not Numeric", "ERROR", MessageBoxButtons.OK)
            inputbox.Text = ""
        Else
            For i = 1 To Len(inputbox.Text)
                If Mid(inputbox.Text, i, 1) <> "0" Or Mid(inputbox.Text, i, 1) <> "1" Then
                    MessageBox.Show("Value Not Binary", "ERROR", MessageBoxButtons.OK)
                    inputbox.Text = ""
                    GoTo skipbin
                End If
            Next
            For x = 1 To Len(inputbox.Text)
                If Mid(inputbox.Text, x, 1) = "1" Then
                    decnum = decnum + 2 ^ (Len(inputbox.Text) - (x - 1))
                End If
            Next
            binnum = inputbox.Text
            inputbox.Text = ""

        End If
        textbox.Text = "Dec = " + decnum.ToString + " Bin = " + binnum.ToString + " Hex = " + hexnum.ToString 
skipbin:
        End Sub
```

Let me explain:

1. The inputbox is the place where the user can input the numbers/operations. The first If checks if the value inputed is a number.
2. Then a check is ran to ensure the number is binary. (this is where im having problems)
3. The conversion is ran. It doesn't work as intended at the moment, but I'm sure I'll get it working.
4. Then the binary and denary values get displayed in a second textbox that I use to display the answers.

The problem I'm having is only with this section: **(again, forgive me for the goto functions)**

```
         For i = 1 To Len(inputbox.Text)
            If Mid(inputbox.Text, i, 1) <> "0" Or Mid(inputbox.Text, i, 1) <> "1" Then
                MessageBox.Show("Value Not Binary", "I AM ERROR", MessageBoxButtons.OK)
                inputbox.Text = ""
                GoTo skipbin
            End If
        Next
```

It's supposed to check each digit if it's a 1 or a 0, and if not, it displays an error and skips the conversion.

What do I need to change to make the input validation work as intended?

Comment: Use Regex: `If Regex.IsMatch(inputbox.Text, "^[01]+$") Then ...`

Comment: @AlexB. While your suggestion would work, I think it may be pitched a little above the OP's current knowledge.

Comment: Yeah, I don't really understand it.

Comment: @AndrewMorton You are probably right. Your solution seems pretty straight forward. I´m not a huge RegEx fan either but for this task it could be understandable for the OP.

Comment: @GregKoc I edited your question a little bit. While it has all the information necessary, it is better to have a direct question; also, "thanks" are not needed. To help you with writing questions in the future, you might want to have a read of [Should I remove 'fluff' when editing questions?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260776/1115360)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `And` instead of `Or`.

When you get a bit of code that you can't figure out why it doesn't work, it is often a good idea to make the minimal bit of code that shows the problem - removing everything else can often lead you to the problem.

In this case, to confirm my answer was correct, I used this:

```
Option Infer On
Option Strict On

Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim s = "000012"
        For i = 1 To Len(s)
            Dim c = Mid(s, i, 1)
            If c <> "0" And c <> "1" Then
                Console.WriteLine("Value Not Binary: {0}", c)

            End If
        Next

        Console.ReadLine()

    End Sub

End Module
```

You can use `AndAlso` instead of `And`: it eliminates any unnecessary processing of the clauses (known as *short-circuiting*). Similarly, there is `OrElse` instead of `Or`.

Comment: @GregKoc Computer And and Or are sort-of the opposite way round from English and and or - it's an easy mistake to make.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is your condition result is always true for any binary number.
try this instead

```
Dim currentChar = CInt(Mid(InputBox.Text, i, 1))
If currentChar <> 0 And currentChar <> 1 Then
    MessageBox.Show("Value Not Binary", "ERROR", MessageBoxButtons.OK)
    InputBox.Text = ""
    GoTo skipbin
End If
```